# Rspec request spec uses assert_template, provided by gem 'rails-controller-testing'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am building a new Rails app using Rails 5.2.0 and rspec 3.7.1. I am trying to follow the recommendations from the rspec team here:

http://rspec.info/blog/2016/07/rspec-3-5-has-been-released/

specifically:

> For new Rails apps: we don't recommend adding the
>   rails-controller-testing gem to your application. The official
>   recommendation of the Rails team and the RSpec core team is to write
>   request specs instead.

These instructions in turn link to this page, which provides an example of a request spec. The example contains the following:

```
expect(response).to render_template(:new)
```

When I include a similar call to `render_template` in my spec, I get the following message:

Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:index)

> NoMethodError:
>     assert_template has been extracted to a gem. To continue using it,
>     add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your Gemfile.

`render_template` is still delegating to `assert_template`, which is apparently provided by rails-controller-testing. But using `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` is not recommended for new apps.

Should I be using a different method to test for rendering, or just include the rails-controller-testing gem despite the recommendation against it?

Comment: I agree the documentation seems to offer conflicting points of view. Rather than use `rails-controller-testing` you might check out https://github.com/rails/rails-dom-testing which is recommended by a member of the Rails team: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950#issuecomment-87001575

Comment: It looks like rails-dom-testing is meant to test the rendered content, and not to test whether a given template was rendered.